# How to view menu and submenus in URL

Tags: menus

I created a menu to my Wordpress website, and I have a menu like this

```
  MENU1
  ..submenu2
  ...submenu3
```

if I click on submenu3/submenu2 then the URL is like,

```
 abc.com/submenu3 or abc.com/submenu2
```

what I exactly want to do is like,

```
 abc.com/menu1/submenu2/submenu3
```

Please reply me your answer, I really need it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to do any back end coding you can create a custom link in the menu panel

[image]

and then drag the submenu3 under the msubmenu2 and then all under menu1
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even though there may be a few factors to consider, assuming that your menu items are pages, to achieve abc.com/menu1/submenu2/submenu3

**You would need to set submenu2 as the parent page os submenu3 and menu1 as parent page for submenu2.**

On the other hand, **if they are not pages or  hierarchical custom post types**, it may prove to be messy with having to redefine a few  rewrite  rules.

Answer (score 0):

login to your wordpress site go to the specific page you want to make child of a page, after opening page on right corner you will see page attribute add the parent page! Woaaah thats easy! go a head..

Answer (score -1):

Assign MENU1 as parent of submenu2 & submenu2 as parent of submenu3

Comment: It would be great if you could also explain as how to assign